How do I refer to time using time8 format in a Macro %do statement in SAS?
I have a variable that stores the current time using the time8 format and I want a macro to run unless the current time is later than 1:00pm, example:
%let time_now=%sysfunc(time(),time8.);

%macro find;
    %do %until (&time_now. gt '13:00:00't);
    {Some Code here}
    %end;

%if &time_now gt '13:00:00't %then %do;
    %put WARNING: The file has not yet appeared and it is after 1pm;
    %abort cancel;
%end;
%mend find;
%find;

I've seen examples where '13:00:00't works in a data step, but it does not seem to be working for me here. What do I replace it with? (Note: I want it to be something similar to the time8. format, not a SAS time which I know would be 46,800, but that is much less clear about what time is being referred to. Also I am stubborn and want to figure this out.)
When I try '13:00:00't it says I am past the time allotted, but that is not true because it is before 1pm. When I try 46,800 it runs as expected so I know it is not a time zone issue. I have also tried using double quotes since it is in a macro but that has not worked either.

Use %SYSEVALF to evaluate a constant representation.
%do %until ( %sysfunc(time()) > %sysevalf('13:00:00't) );


Comparisons in macro statements like %IF or %WHILE or %UNTIL will by default use %EVAL() which can only handle integer arithmetic.  If you want to use floating point comparisons or literals then just add an explicit call to %SYSEVALF() to your condition.
%do %until( %sysevalf(&time_now. gt '13:00:00't) );


It wont let me accept both yours and Richards suggestions as the solution but this also works . Thank you!

Both will work when the times are whole numbers of seconds.  But Richard's will fail when fractions of a second (floating point values) are involved.

I've solved my own question, but leaving here in case anyone else ever needs it. I need to treat &time_now like a character and then I can compare it to the time as a character and you dont even need the t format.
%do %until ("&time_now" gt '13:00:00');

%if "&time_now" gt '13:00:00' %then %do;


This will give you the wrong result.  In the macro language, quotation marks are just text, and they will be part of the value compared. A double quote sorts lower than a single quote, so I would expect your code to create an infinite loop.  It could work if you use double quotes for both values, but it is clearer to uses %sysevalf and do a numeric comparison.

It does seem to work actually. I tested it a few times and had the expected outcome, but I agree using %sysevalf is better so I will be updating my code.

Even if you fix the quotes so they match you would need to make sure that TIME_NOW is generated with the TOD format instead of the TIME format to insure that it has the leading zero for times before 10 AM.
